# Reconstructing a function from its variants that negate one argument

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, graph-theory, graph-reconstruction

Call two functions $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ from complex numbers to complex numbers *equivalent* if they are the same up to the order of their arguments.  Formally: there is a permutation $\sigma$ such that for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ we have $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=h(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})$.

For function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $1\le i\le n$, define
$$f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},-x_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$$
(just the $i$-th argument is negated).

Now, you are given the multiset $\mathcal D(f)$ which contains the equivalence classes of $f_i$ for $1\le i\le n$.  (I'm calling it a multiset because I don't want you to remove duplicates; $\mathcal D(f)$ has exactly $n$ elements.) **Can you determine the equivalence class of $f$?**

**My question:** Has this problem been formulated before?  If so, references please!

To show that the question is hard in general, even for polynomials, I'll note that it includes Stanley's unsolved [switching reconstruction conjecture](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/63.pdf) for graphs.  For a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and edge set $E$, define
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \prod_{i<j;~ ij\in E} (1+x_ix_y) \prod_{i<j;~ij\notin E}(1-x_ix_j).$$
Now $f_i$ corresponds to switching $G$ at vertex $i$. It is unknown whether $G$ can be reconstructed from $\mathcal D(f)$ for $n\gt 4$.  In the case of $n=4$, there is a counterexample: consider a 4-cycle and the graph with no edges.

The choice of complex numbers was arbitrary; you can consider any domain and range for which the question is meaningful.

Some facts can be determined by the methods used for other reconstruction problems.  For example, if $n$ is odd then the equivalence class of $f$ can be reconstructed from $\mathcal D(f)$: it is the only equivalence class occurring an odd number of times in the multiset union of the multisets $\mathcal D(f_i)$. Beáta Faller and I will publish some results on symmetries of non-reconstructible functions. But what is known already?

Comment: It looks like there was supposed to be a link to the Stanley conjecture, but there isn't...?